# How to write elegant verification methods

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have `Notifications` which can be marked as read by a `Employee`.
This works as following:

1. User/Employee opens Notification (Webpage)
2. User clicks on "mark as read"
3. User has to insert his EmployeeNumber and click "confirm"
4. User gets feedback if there was an error

In my example I have to verify if the `Employee` with the entered EmployeeNumber exists in my Database and if so load the entry.

I need this verification at multiple places so I thought I can extract it into a Method to D.R.Y.

**EmployeeService:**

```
public class EmployeeService : BaseService
{
    public static Employee VerifyEmployeeNumber(ISession session, string employeeNumber)
    {
        if (employeeNumber.IsNullOrWhitespace())
            throw new ArgumentNullException();

        Employee employee = session.Query<Employee>().FirstOrDefault(x => x.Number == employeeNumber);
        if (employee == null)
            throw new ArgumentException();

        return employee;
    }

}
```

**NotificationService**

```
public class NotificationService : BaseService
{
    public string SetNotificationAsRead(long notificationId, string employeeNumber)
    {
        Employee employee;
        try
        {
            employee = EmployeeService.VerifyEmployeeNumber(Session, employeeNumber);
        }
        catch (ArgumentNullException)
        {
            return "No Employeenumber was entered";
        }
        catch (ArgumentException)
        {
            return "No Employee exists with this number";
        }

        //Update my notification as read
        return null;
    }
}
```

**NotificationController:**

```
 public JsonResult MarkAsRead(long notificationId, string employeeNumber)
 {
     string errormessage = NotificationService.SetNotificationAsRead(notificationId, employeeNumber);

     if (errormessage.IsNotNullOrWhitespace())
         return Error(errormessage);

     return Success();
 }
```

The JSON gets parsed at the front-end.

**Problem:**
I also need to verify my EmployeeNumber in other services like my `BarcodeService`. I also have to show the same errors.
So again I have to write the `try-catch` and hardcode the error-messages.

This seems clumsy and awful.

How can I implement this in a better way.
It seems like I need a method which can return an error **or** the employee which is not possible in c#

Thanks in advance.

**Aditional Information:**

- Generic-Verification is not needed
- @I Stanley - I could put the messages into the Employeeclass but if I only need them at one place I don't think its too bad writing them hardcoded into the verification-method
- I think the biggest Problem is how to get error-messages from the Businesslogic (Services) to the User (Controllers -> JSON -> Webpage)

**Possible improvement 1:**
I thought about **only** verifying if the employee exists with my `VerifyEmployeeNumber` and if no error was returned the employee gets loaded from the DB. This has the downside of 2 DB-accesses.

Comment: You could create an interface that will be responsible in validating the properties you need to validate, then this interface can be used by your Services as a dependency. Dependency injection will help you on this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem here is that elegance is a largely subjective trait. I can suggest some things that might help you encapsulate your code better and prevent duplication of lines, but what I suggest may be abhorrent to the next person.

It seems that you are asking about two different problems, or at least a problem that can be split into two parts:

1. How to handle your error messages so you don't hard code them each time
2. How to handle your verification method so that you don't duplicate your try/catch blocks every time.

Ignoring for the sake of it any doubts regarding the overall design approach...

The error messages bit is pretty easy to at least clean up - make the error strings either part of an error class or part of the class itself. For example, you could do:

```
public class Employee : BaseClass
{ 
  ...

  //Error Messages for Employee checks
  public static string ErrorNotFound = "No Employee exists with this number";
  public static string ErrorInvalid = "Invalid Employee Number";

  ...
}
```

Then you could call that string by doing `Employee.ErrorNotFound` rather than writing it out each time.

Alternatively you make a class/struct that holds all your error messages called ErrorMsg or something and call `ErrorMsg.EmployeeNotFound` instead. This in itself is tidier than hard-coded strings, but further advantages will become clear in the second section.

Now, the try/catch stuff. If you're intent on sticking with your use of exceptions (see the notes below), then depending on how generic you want to go, just repeat what you did with the EmployeeService and create a method that encapsulates the try/catch. There's no reason why this shouldn't be a function within the EmployeeService, as that's what this service will **ALWAYS** be supplying, right? Whether or not that employee exists or the input is valid.

If you want to make it interesting, and have a function that handles all validation regardless of whether it's an employee or some other form of validation, you could try playing around with [Delegates](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173172.aspx), and create a function which will call the correct validation function and then output the related error message. I won't go into details as there are hundreds of ways to do this correctly and I don't know how complicated your system is. There may be no reason to create a generic validation handler function if the only thing you'll ever need to validate is EmployeeNumber.

There are a couple of things to note:

1) your use of exceptions is controversial at best. Most guidelines you will see ([MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/seyhszts(v=vs.110).aspx), for instance) highly recommend using exceptions **only to catch unexpected behaviour**, not as a standard form of flow control. In these functions, you are using them effectively as return values - it is highly likely that these exceptions will be hit repeatedly during normal use. Far better to return `NULL`, or some "No employee found" object which can then be handled via standard flow control.

The advantage of this is that a) you don't have to have so many try/catch statements and b) it standardizes what you have to check for to see if you found an employee - if it's not NULL, great, you found one. I don't need to go looking to see what kind of exception was thrown.

2) Is it necessary to distinguish between "no employee with this number" and "no employee number entered"? Both amount to the same thing. If you just use a single error message that encompasses both "no Employee found with this number" or similar. If you are set on having different error messages, pass a string into the function by reference and have it populated on error, then print the contents of the string for the error message if the function returns NULL.

The chances are that everyone who answers this will pick up on different things depending on what depth they go to and what portion they focus on (There are probably design aspects that I have missed which may well make anything I've suggested invalid!). It's up to you to consider which advice you want to take.

I have no idea how you're going to choose the "right" answer...

Comment: I like the idea of returning `NULL` and passing a errorstring object into the method.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have problem with your `Employee VerifyEmployeeNumber(ISession session, string employeeNumber)` method design. You mix both command and query by validating an entity and returning it. That's why you have a problem with separation.

I would rather query for employee and then verify him in a separate method. Note that you are trying to `SetNotificationAsRead` but additionally you query for an employee and validate values. This is an evidence of bad design.

Wouldn't be better to just:

```
 public JsonResult MarkAsRead(long notificationId, string employeeNumber)
 {
     var employee = _session.Query<Employee>().FirstOrDefault(x => x.Number == employeeNumber);
     var error = EmployeeService.VerifyEmployee(_session, employee);
     if (errormessage.IsNotNullOrWhitespace())
         return Error(errormessage);

     NotificationService.SetNotificationAsRead(notificationId, employee);   
     return Success();
 }
```

It is just a concept but you should get an idea.

Comment: I cannot verify the employee afterwards, because if the Number is not correct no employee will be found in the DB.

Comment: @Altoyr You should check whether `employee == null` in your `VerifyEmployee` method.